# How to set Custom Cursor Adapter to list when using LoaderManager

Tags: android

In my onCreate:

ListView Definition:

```
 listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
```

Loader Manager:

```
getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, new LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>() {
    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        return new CursorLoader(ListDetailActivity.this,
                ReceiptProvider.URI_RECEIPT, Receipt.FIELDS, null, null,
                null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor c) {
        System.out.println("Cursor: " + c);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {

    }
});
```

My custom Cursor adapter:

```
 private class CurAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

        public CurAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
            super(context, c, flags);
        }


        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

            TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            String name = (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("receipt_name")));

            tv.setText(name);
            //setImage(image, iv);

        }

        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

            View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_layout, null);

            return view;

        }


    }
```

How do I set the Cursor to list now? I know how to do it for a SimpleCursorAdapter, but I am clueless on how to do it for a Cursor Adapter, any hints?

For now I am doing it like:

```
  @Override
            public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor c) {
               CurAdapter Cur = new CurAdapter(ListDetailActivity.this, c, 0);
                listView.setAdapter(Cur);
            }
```

It works properly, but I am not sure if this is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

maybe so:

```
listView.setAdapter(new CurAdapter(this, cursor));
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to set your adapter to listview in init method and hold the reference to adapter as a field. it is ok to pass null as a cursor parameter. There are two methods in CursorAdapter class changeCursor and swapCursor, use one you need to set the cursor in onLoadFinished.

**Update**: https://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/handle-results.html